# Already Installed SQL Server - How to run click one application with two versions of sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new to database and deploying applications using .NET

I have developed an application and created its click one application.

However it's working fine on my system, but when I install it on another system it says:

> *Prerequisite check for system component SQL Server 2008 Express failed with the following error message:
>
>   SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) cannot upgrade the existing instance of SQL Server 2005 Express (x64 WoW) named 'SQLEXPRESS'. Uninstall this instance of SQL Server 2005 Express and retry installing SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64).*
>
> *See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\SYSUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3E78.tmp\install.log' for more information.*

So from this its quite understandable SQL Server 2005 is installed and I need to uninstall it to install SQL Server 2008 which I have included in my prerequisites.

But is there any escape from it, let say that in background it auto upgrade the system from 2005 to 2008 to avoid user irritation.

Or may be any mechanism using which we can use both the versions on one system. Ideally I think that it will not happen because we cannot run two servers at a time. But still i am limited to my knowledge.

Also, everyday we install so many applications on our system, it never ask us for SQL Server thing, everything just get installed with simple `Next -> Next -> Finish` options. Is there any simpler way for the installer. So that when someone is installing the application on his/her system, it won't bother them with so much of technical's.

Answer (score 1):

All versions and editions of SQL Server support unattended installation. Start from [Install SQL Server 2012 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) and pick the version you're targeting. For a SQL Express specific example, see [Configuring SQL Express During Installation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/09/20/configuring-sql-express-during-installation.aspx). There is even a white paper about [Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562.aspx).